# color blending using PathGradientBrush

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have been stuck at this problem for few hours but can n't seem to make progress. I am trying to draw a rectangle which shows like the following

[image]

with a lightgrey border line. I am successfully able to draw the grey border line rectangle, but i am having trouble filling the rectangle.
There are 9 colors and i would like them to be space equally across the width of my rectangle.

My Code Looks like the following

```
            using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gp.AddRectangle(rect);

                using (var pgb = new PathGradientBrush(gp))
                {
                    var pos = new[] { 0f, .125f, .25f, .375f, .5f, .625f, .75f, .875f, 1f };
                    var b = new Blend
                                 {
                                     Positions = pos,
                                     Factors = new[] { .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f }
                                 };
                    var cb = new ColorBlend
                    {
                        Positions = pos,
                        Colors = new[]
                                                   {
                                                       Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 79),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(81, 0, 123),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(152, 0, 118),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(211, 0, 62),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(245, 31, 0),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(255, 175, 0),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 100),
                                                       Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
                                                   }
                    };

                    pgb.Blend = b;
                    pgb.InterpolationColors = cb;
                    pgb.CenterPoint = new PointF(rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2);
                    pgb.FocusScales = new PointF(.5f, .5f);
                    bufferedGraphics.Graphics.FillPath(pgb, gp);
                }
            }
```

but this ends up producing 
[image]
Please ignore the inconsistent sizes of the two graphics.

Is this possible to do and if so how can i change my method to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `PathGradientBrush`, use a `LinearGradientBrush`, because you want to draw the colors in a straight block. And (at least for me) it's easier to understand what happens.

I've tried the following code in a framework 2.0 project, s sorry for removing C#4.0 syntax.

```
        using (LinearGradientBrush lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Black, Color.White, 0f)) {
            float[] pos = new float[] { 0f, .125f, .25f, .375f, .5f, .625f, .75f, .875f, 1f };
            Blend b = new Blend();
            b.Positions = pos;
            b.Factors = new float[] { .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f, .125f };
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Positions = pos;
            cb.Colors = new Color[] {
                Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0),
                Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 79),
                Color.FromArgb(81, 0, 123),
                Color.FromArgb(152, 0, 118),
                Color.FromArgb(211, 0, 62),
                Color.FromArgb(245, 31, 0),
                Color.FromArgb(255, 175, 0),
                Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 100),
                Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255),
            };
            lgb.Blend = b;
            lgb.InterpolationColors = cb;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, rect);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate, You are a rockstar !